# Typescript this being overriden by jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, typescript

When you use a jquery hover binding like `$(".element").hover(functionHoverIn,functionHoverOut)`, jquery seems to pass the element that was hovered as `this`. Like so:

```
$('.element').hover(function(e) { 
         $(this).attr("data-hovered", "true");
         //do whatever else
     }, function(e) {
         //etc
     }
}
```

Its useful, so that inside these anonymous functions we have access to the element via `this` or `$(this)`.
However, it seems to conflict with typescript. Or perhaps I don't understand something:

```
class FancyHover {
    HoverElement:JQuery;

    constructor(HoverElement:JQuery) {
        this.HoverElement = HoverElement;
        this.HoverElement.hover(this.HandleHover, this.HandleHover);
    }

    HandleHover(event:JQueryEventObject):void {
        $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass("hovered");

        this.OtherFunction(); //Throws error
        //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'OtherFunction' 
    }

    OtherFunction():void {
        //do anything
    }
}
```

Ideally, I wish to pass a function (such as `this.HandleHover`) into the `.hover(functionIn,functionOut)` call instead of anonymous functions. However, when I do this, I lose my ability to reference the current instance of FancyHover. Maybe I can somehow pass the current instance to the function HandleHover?

Comment: This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `this` provided from the callback as well as the `this` of the class instance, you'll need to do that manually, e.g.:

```
constructor() {
    // ...
    var self = this;
    this.HoverElement.hover(function(event) { self.HandleHover(event, this); });
}

HandleHover(event: JQueryEventObject, jqueryThis: JQuery) {
    $(jqueryThis).attr(/*etc*/);
    this.OtherFunction();
}
```

Comment: I suppose this solves the problem. Thanks! Though it is quite ugly.

Comment: Update: 

`this.HoverElement.hover(event => this.handlerover(event))`  or `this.handleElement.hover(this.handlehover.bind(this))`